# Action is being dispatched but state is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a simple map app with react-map-gl. I have some onClick events in other places, but the ones in my map are not working as desired. Specifically my modals are not rendering.

My modal actions:

```
import {TOGGLE_PROFILE, TOGGLE_MAP, TOGGLE_LOCATION} from './modalTypes';

export const toggleProfile = () => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_PROFILE
    }
}

export const toggleMap = (lat, lng) => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_MAP,
        payload: {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: lng
        }
    }
}

export const toggleLocation = (id) => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_LOCATION,
        payload: {
            locationId: id
        }
    }
}
```

My modal reducer:

```
import {TOGGLE_PROFILE, TOGGLE_MAP, TOGGLE_LOCATION} from './modalTypes';

const initialState = {
    profileOpen: false,
    mapOpen: false,
    longitude: '',
    latitude: '',
    locationOpen: false,
    locationId: ''
}

const modalReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                profileOpen: !state.profileOpen
            }
        case TOGGLE_MAP:
            return {
                ...state,
                mapOpen: !state.mapOpen,
                longitude: state.mapOpen === true ? '' : action.payload.longitude, 
                latitude: state.mapOpen === true ? '' : action.payload.latitude
            }
        case TOGGLE_LOCATION:
            return {
                ...state,
                locationOpen: !state.locationOpen,
                locationId: action.payload.locationId
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default modalReducer;
```

And then I have three modals. toggleProfile works perfectly, but then toggleMap updates the state, and toggleLocation doesn't even detect dispatch the action, even if the click is detected.

How can I eve begin to debug this and find out what's wrong?

EDIT to add the component making the calls, I'm sorry if it gets too long, I'm open to post elsewhere:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getUserLocation, updateMap, getLocationsRequest, getUser, toggleMap, toggleLocation} from '../../redux';
import './mapPage.scss';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import ReactMapGL, {Marker} from 'react-map-gl';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from '../NavBar/NavBar';
import ProfileModal from '../ProfileModal/ProfileModal';
import MapModal from '../MapModal/MapModal';
import LocationModal from '../LocationModal/LocationModal';

function MapPage({viewport, getUserLocation, updateMap, getLocations, locations, getUser, toggleMap}) {

    const history = useHistory();

    // Using hooks to get the user and their location, because what do we say to class components and componentDidMount? NOT TODAY!
    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.token){
            getUser(localStorage.token);
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coords => {
                getUserLocation(coords.coords.latitude, coords.coords.longitude);
                getLocations(coords.coords.latitude, coords.coords.longitude);
            });
        } else {
            history.push('/');
        }
    }, [getUserLocation, getLocations, getUser, history]);

    // When the user drags the map, the coordinates are updated in the state and the map gets redrawn.
    const onViewportChange = (viewport) => {
        updateMap(viewport);
        getLocations(viewport.latitude, viewport.longitude);
        getMarkers();
    }

    // When the user drags the map into an area with reviews, markers are pulled to show how many reviews each location has.
    const getMarkers = () =>{
        return locations.map(location => {
            return (
                <Marker key={location.id} offsetLeft={-25} offsetTop={-70} latitude={parseFloat(location.lat)} longitude={parseFloat(location.lng)}>
                    <div className="marker-styles" onClick={() =>locationClickHandler(location.id)} >
                        <p>{location.review_count}</p>
                    </div>
                </Marker>
            );
        });
    }

    const locationClickHandler = id => {
        toggleLocation(id);
    }

    // When the user clicks on the map, open a modal for creating a new location with review
    const mapClickHandler = (info) => {
        toggleMap(info.lngLat[1], info.lngLat[0]);
    }

    // Importing Mapbox's API key from my environment variables.
    const TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN;

    // This is the map component with its corresponding options.
    return (
        <>
            <LocationModal />
            <NavBar />
            <ReactMapGL 
            {...viewport}
            className={"map-container"}
            onClick={(info) => mapClickHandler(info)}
            attributionControl={false}
            onViewportChange={(viewport) => onViewportChange(viewport)}
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10"
            mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}>
            {getMarkers()}
            </ReactMapGL>
            <ProfileModal />
            <MapModal />
        </>
    )
}


// Bringing the state from redux...
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        viewport: state.viewport,
        locations: state.locations
    };
};

// ...as well as some actions...
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getUserLocation: (lat, lng) => dispatch(getUserLocation(lat, lng)),
        updateMap: (viewport) => dispatch(updateMap(viewport)),
        getLocations: (lat, lng) => dispatch(getLocationsRequest(lat, lng)),
        getUser: (token) => dispatch(getUser(token)),
        toggleMap: (lat, lng) => dispatch(toggleMap(lat, lng)),
        toggleLocation: (id) => dispatch(toggleLocation(id))
    }
}

// ...and finally sending them back to the component as props.
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapPage);
```

Comment: Do you have the redux-dev-tools installed and running in your browser so you can examine your redux store live? Can you manually dispatch the actions and see your redux state update? Are the actions correctly wrapped in a call to dispatch? Are the components connected to the redux store? Can you include the component code using these actions and consuming state?

Comment: Can you post the component from where you are dispatching this action

Comment: @DrewReese I have Redux devtools and I can dispatch my actions manually. AFAIK my action are wrapped in a dispatch call. Karthik I updated the post.

Comment: You missed destructuring `toggleLocation` in the props in the function signature. 8 total props from `mapStateToProps` (2) and `mapDispatchToProps` (6), only 7 destructured props. If you define `propTypes` for all the props that can help catch and at least alert/warn you to missing props.

Comment: Sorry what's the function signature? And how I forgot to destructure toggleLocation? Also, where can I read about this proptypes stuff? Sorry complete newbie to Redux.

Comment: EDIT: It's working now, thank you so much. I had indeed forgotten to destructure toggleLocation, but I'm curious about the proptyes stuff.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html